# Use the same javascript function in different selects

Tags: javascript, html

I need to use the same JavaScript function called `Cerca2` in 3 separated selects. The first one works, but the others do not. I've tried to fix the problem by myself but I can't find where it is.

EDIT: code edited, now work perfectly, tnx for all the suggestion and support guys ^^
This is the html:

```
  <body>

  Ricerca per Nome: <input type="text" maxlength="20"/>
  <input id="cerca1" type="button" value="Cerca" /><br/><br/>

Ricerca personaggi per Fazione:
<select id="factionSelect">
    <option>UNSC</option>
    <option>Covenant</option>
    <option>Flood</option>
    <option>Precursori</option>
</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="cerca2" selectid="factionSelect" type="button" value="Cerca"/>

<br/><br/>

Ricerca armi per tipo:
<select id="weaponSelect">
    <option>cinetiche</option>
    <option>plasma</option>
    <option>energia</option>
</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="cerca5" selectid="weaponSelect" type="button" value="Cerca"/>

<br/><br/>

Ricerca Veicoli per impiego:
<select id="vehicleSelect">
    <option>terrestri</option>
    <option>volanti</option>
    <option>Astronavi</option>
</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="cerca6" selectid="vehicleSelect" type="button" value="Cerca"/>

  <input id="cerca3" type="button" value="Mostra tutto"/>
  <input id="cerca4" type="button" value="Ricerca casuale"/><br/><br/>

  <hr id="barra"/><br/><p>Risultati ricerca:</p>

  <div id="risultati">
  <ol id="ricerca">
  <li class="vuoto"></li>
  </ol>

  </div>
</body>
```

This is the JavaScript:

```
function Profilo(nom, appar, prof, grup, img){

    this.nome = nom;
    this.apparizione = appar;
    this.profilo = prof;
    this.gruppo = grup;
    this.immagine = img;
}


function Archivio(){

    this.lista = [];

    this.inizializza = function(nodo){
        var schede = nodo.getElementsByTagName("scheda");

        for(var i = 0; i<schede.length; i++){

            var categoria = schede[i].getAttribute("categoria");
            var nomi = schede[i].getElementsByTagName("nome");
            var nome = nomi[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var apparizioni = schede[i].getElementsByTagName("apparizione");
            var apparizione = apparizioni[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var profili = schede[i].getElementsByTagName("profilo");
            var profilo = profili[0].firstChild.nodeValue;  
            var immagini = schede[i].getElementsByTagName("immagine");
            var immagine =  immagini[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

            var scheda = new Profilo(nome, apparizione, profilo, categoria,immagine);
            this.lista.push(scheda);
        }
    }

    this.cerca1 = function(testo){
        var risultato = [];
        var trovato = 0;
        var i = 0;

        while(i<this.lista.length && trovato == 0){
            if(this.lista[i].nome == testo)
            {
                trovato = 1;
                risultato.push(this.lista[i]);
            }
            else
                i++;
        }

        if(trovato == 1)
            return risultato;
        else
        {
            risultato[0] = null;
            return risultato;
        }
    }

    this.cerca2 = function(testo){
        var risultati = [];

        for(var i = 0; i<this.lista.length; i++){
            if(this.lista[i].gruppo == testo)
                risultati.push(this.lista[i]);
        }
        return risultati;
    }



    this.cerca3 = function(numero){
        var risultati = [];

        risultati.push(this.lista[numero]);

        return risultati;
    }

    this.genera = function(valori){  // genera la lista con gli elementi di xml
        var s = "";

        if(valori[0] == null)
            s = "Nessun risultato";
        else{   
            for(var i = 0; i<valori.length; i++)
                s = s + '<li><span class="trovato" onclick="mostra(this);">' + valori[i].nome + "  " + '</span><br/><ol class="nascosto"><li class="nopallino2"> <img src='+ valori[i].immagine+'> <br/><br/>Profilo: '+ valori[i].profilo +'<br/>Apparizione: ' + valori[i].apparizione +'</li></ol></li><br/><br/>';
        } 
        return s;   
    }

    this.nascondi = function(){
        var liste = document.getElementsByTagName("ol");

        for(var i = 0; i<liste.length; i++){
            if(liste[i].className == "nascosto")
                liste[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

function cercagruppo(){

    /*var elenco = document.getElementById("ricerca");
    var menu = document.getElementsByTagName("select");

    var scelta = menu[0];
    var gruppo = scelta.value;
    var schede = contenitore.cerca2(gruppo);
    elenco.innerHTML = contenitore.genera(schede);
    contenitore.nascondi(); */


    var elenco = document.getElementById("ricerca");
    var menu = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("selectid"));
    var group = menu.value;
    var schede = contenitore.cerca2(group);
    elenco.innerHTML = contenitore.genera(schede);
    contenitore.nascondi();


}


function mostra(nome){

    var testo = nome.nextSibling.nextSibling;

    if(testo.style.display == "none")
        testo.style.display = "block"

    else
        testo.style.display = "none"
}

// funzione che cerca le schede relative all'oggetto cercato digitando il nome
function cercanome(){

    var casella = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var nome;
    var elenco = document.getElementById("ricerca");
    var scheda;

    nome = casella[0].value;

    scheda = contenitore.cerca1(nome);

    elenco.innerHTML = contenitore.genera(scheda);

    contenitore.nascondi();
}

// funzione per mostrare tutte le schede
function tutto(){

    var elenco = document.getElementById("ricerca");

    elenco.innerHTML = contenitore.genera(contenitore.lista);

    contenitore.nascondi(); 
}


function generaCasuale(){

    var numerogenerato = Math.floor(Math.random()*(parseInt(contenitore.lista.length-1)+1));

    if(numerogenerato == randomglobale){
        while(numerogenerato == randomglobale)
            numerogenerato = Math.floor(Math.random()*(parseInt(contenitore.lista.length-1)+1));
    }

    randomglobale = numerogenerato;
    return numerogenerato;
}

// funzione di ricerca casuale 
function casuale(){

    var elenco = document.getElementById("ricerca");
    var numero = generaCasuale();
    var scheda = contenitore.cerca3(numero);

    elenco.innerHTML = contenitore.genera(scheda);

    contenitore.nascondi();
}


var contenitore = new Archivio();
var randomglobale;

function inizializza(){

    var c1 = document.getElementById("cerca1");
    var c2 = document.getElementById("cerca2");
    var c3 = document.getElementById("cerca3");
    var c4 = document.getElementById("cerca4");
    var c5 = document.getElementById("cerca5");
    var c6 = document.getElementById("cerca6");


    c1.onclick = cercanome;
    c2.onclick = cercagruppo;
    c3.onclick = tutto;
    c4.onclick = casuale;
    c5.onclick = cercagruppo;
    c6.onclick = cercagruppo;


    var nodo = caricaXML("elenco.xml");
    contenitore.inizializza(nodo);
}

window.onload = inizializza;
```

Comment: Please take the time to create a minimal example that replicates the problem. I doubt all that code is needed to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: So what error do you get at runtime? That should tell you what the actual issue is. Open the development console of your browser (typically F12, but depends on the browser you use) and check the "console" tab. That is where javascript (usually) logs stuff to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I totally understand the question, but in this code, c5 and c6 are all getting the cerca2 inputs :

```
var c1 = document.getElementById("cerca1");
var c2 = document.getElementById("cerca2");
var c3 = document.getElementById("cerca3");
var c4 = document.getElementById("cerca4");
var c5 = document.getElementById("cerca2");
var c6 = document.getElementById("cerca2");
```

Answer (score 1):

In several parts of your code, you select all elements of a certain type, but only use the first such element.

For example:

```
function cercagruppo(){
    ...
    var menu = document.getElementsByTagName("select"); // gets all "select" elements
    var scelta = menu[0]; // gets value of first "select" element
    ...
}
```

And also:

```
function cercanome(){
    var casella = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); // gets all "input" elements
    ...
    nome = casella[0].value; // gets value of first "input" element
    ...
}
```

If you want to get the values from all `select` and `input` elements, you'll need to do so explicitly, such as by looping through the `menu` and `casella` arrays instead of selecting only their first items.

**Edit: Suggested approach to refactoring code**

Having looked at your code a bit more, here's the approach I think you should take:

1. In your HTML, add an ID attribute to each of your `select` elements.
2. Add an attribute to your "cerca2", "cerca5", and "cerca6" input buttons that indicates the ID of the corresponding `select` element
3. You can then access the attribute in the `cercagruppo()` function and use it to select the corresponding `select` element.

Your `cercagruppo()` function would look more like this:

```
function cercagruppo(){
    var ol = document.getElementById("ricerca");
    var selection = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("selectid"));
    var group = selection.value;
    var tabs = contenitore.cerca2(group);
    ol.innerHTML = contenitore.genera(tabs);
    contenitore.nascondi();
}
```

Your HTML would end up looking more like this:

```html
Ricerca personaggi per Fazione:
<select id="factionSelect">
    <option>UNSC</option>
    <option>Covenant</option>
    <option>Flood</option>
    <option>Precursori</option>
</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="cerca2" selectid="factionSelect" type="button" value="Cerca"/>
<br/><br/>
Ricerca armi per tipo:
<select id="weaponSelect">
    <option>cinetiche</option>
    <option>plasma</option>
    <option>energia</option>
</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="cerca5" selectid="weaponSelect" type="button" value="Cerca"/>
<br/><br/>
Ricerca Veicoli per impiego:
<select id="vehicleSelect">
    <option>terrestri</option>
    <option>volanti</option>
    <option>Astronavi</option>
</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="cerca6" selectid="vehicleSelect" type="button" value="Cerca"/>
```

**Edit edit**

And of course, you should also fix the error that @mgarant pointed out:

```
var c1 = document.getElementById("cerca1");
var c2 = document.getElementById("cerca2");
var c3 = document.getElementById("cerca3");
var c4 = document.getElementById("cerca4");
var c5 = document.getElementById("cerca5"); // fixed
var c6 = document.getElementById("cerca6"); // fixed
```

Comment: hmm ok ill'try, tnx for the help

Comment: ok i've tryed but im not good,
how i can gets all "select" elements ?

Comment: @Refarth I updated my answer with a suggestion. And I got to learn some Italian while reading your code... Grazie!

Comment: tnx i will try now ! sorry for the italian words all around xD